# For loop in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
src_ch_id;src_ch_name;src_ch_desc;src_table_name
aa;q1;11;DataTable_4
bb;q2;22;DataTable_4
cc;q3;33;DataTable_4
```

With this dataframe I will create an insert for every row to a database. For testing I will print the parameters.

```
for index in channeldef_data_df:    
   src_ch_id = channeldef_data_df.iloc[[index], channeldef_data_df.columns.get_loc('src_ch_id')]
   print('--')
   print(src_ch_id)
```

I gives the following error:

`".iloc requires numeric indexers, got ['src_ch_id']"`

I think the problem is the `[index]` part in the code. What is my mistake  in the loop?

Comment: just as an aside, why cant you bulk append to the database? row by row is quite slow.

Comment: The tables of the database are not identical and sometimes the data in the source are in different tables, but in the target they should be in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows) to Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.
like `for index, row in channeldef_data_df.iterrows():`

```py
>>> for index,_ in channeldef_data_df.iterrows():
...     src_ch_id = channeldef_data_df.iloc[[index], channeldef_data_df.columns.get_loc('src_ch_id')]
...     print(src_ch_id)
...
0    aa
Name: src_ch_id, dtype: object
1    bb
Name: src_ch_id, dtype: object
2    cc
Name: src_ch_id, dtype: object
```

You are using `for index in channeldef_data_df:` it will only return column names in your code.

```py
>>> for index in channeldef_data_df:
...     print(index)
...
src_ch_id
src_ch_name
src_ch_desc
src_table_name
```

Comment: @Algha Glad it helped you. if you found it useful please upvote and any solution you find right then accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract src_ch_id and print, may be you can use `itertuples()`

```
for index in channeldef_data_df.itertuples():    
    src_ch_id = index.src_ch_id
    print('--')
    print(src_ch_id)
```

This way you get src_ch_id for each row